# Encontrar diferenças entre arrays, com probabilidade de variação

Tags: python, array, comparação, numpy

Boa tarde pessoal, estou lendo sobre a função setdiff1d da biblioteca numpy (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.setdiff1d.html).

Ela serve basicamente para expressar os valores diferentes entre 2 arrays, por exemplo (encontrado no próprio link):

```
>>> a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 1])
>>> b = np.array([3, 4, 5, 6])
>>> np.setdiff1d(a, b)
array([1, 2])
```

Eu gostaria de saber se tem alguma função que permita inserir uma porcentagem de variação nos valores a serem comparados.

Explico, como mostrado no exemplo, a função setdiff1d vai retornar os valores que são exatamente difrentes entre os 2 arrays.

Porém, caso eu esteja trabalhando com floats, e quero permitir uma porcentagem de variação entre esses valores, por exemplo, considerar 3.35 e 3.34 entre dois arrays como valores iguais, tem alguma função específica para trabalhar dessa forma, onde eu possa setar como argumento uma margem de variação entre os valores a serem comparados?

grato.

Answer (score 1):

Tenta assim:

```
limit = 0.01
np.unique(a[(np.abs(np.subtract.outer(a,b)) > limit).all(1)])
```

Comment: O AP quer uma porcentagem de variação, não um valor específico. Seria construtivo explicar a lógica de funcionamento do código.